# Partition on existing table with millions of records

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, database-partitioning

I have table name `builds` it look likes

```
CREATE TABLE `builds` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `testplan_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'undefined',
 `creation_ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `name` (`testplan_id`,`name`),
 KEY `testplan_id` (`testplan_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2074288 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
```

I want to create partitions on build based on creation_ts. I am trying

```
Alter Table builds  PARTITION BY RANGE (TO_DAYS(creation_ts))
      ( PARTITION p1 values less than (TO_DAYS('2015-05-07'))
```

in phpMyadmin but it is showing error "unrecognised alter operation";
I am using MYSQL Server version: 5.7.11.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using? Does that command work through the MySQL command line client? Does it work if you use the "Partition table" link of the "Structure" tab in order to use the graphical interface?

Comment: Before fixing the problem, let's decide whether partitioning will be of any benefit.  Partitioning does not inherently provide _any_ performance; only a few rare use cases benefit.  What is your use case?  Let's see your main `SELECTs`.